# Can't update my table in SQLite using express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am trying to update few records in table in database but I got  `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` every time I try. Connection works fine because I tried to post new records and it worked without problems.
This is my backend code:

```
 module.exports = function (server, db) {
  // function to insert object to db
  function insertTickets(ticket) {
    const stmt = db.prepare(
      "UPDATE tickets SET userid=?, concertid=?, booked=? WHERE ticketid=?"
    );
    stmt.run(ticket.ticketid, ticket.userid, ticket.concertid, ticket.booked);
    console.log(stmt);
  }

  server.put("/data/tickets", (request, response) => {
    const tickets = request.body;
    console.log(request.body);

    try {
      tickets.forEach((ticket) => {
        insertTickets(ticket);
      });
      response.send("tickets inserted to database");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Data I am trying to update is an array with objects:

```
const tickets = [
{ticketid: 1, userid: 1, concertid: 1, booked: 1},
{ticketid: 3, userid: 1, concertid: 1, booked: 1}]
```

Interesting part is, first record is updated only when i try to update two.

**UPDATE:**
problem solved. I deleted concertid=? and concert parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't you indicate fields in `SET` block without `ticket`?

Comment: yes you are right, but it still didnt solve the problem.

Comment: If it's still about FOREIGN KEY constraint then check if a user or concert exists with id = 1

Comment: Isolved the problem. I just deleted concertid=? and concertid parameter. I dont need that to be changed anyway. I dont know why couldnt i update concerts but its work without it.